# A classical sequence

Tags: riddle

What should fill the blank to complete the sequence?

> G G G _ F F F D

From `Brain Games: Lower Your Brain Age in Minutes a Day (Brain Games Series Collection #3)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could it be

> Eb

Because

> *Symphony No. 5 in C Minor*, by Beethoven, follows the notes G G G Eb F F F D

Also,

> The title hints at a classical music piece.

Comment: Yes exactly right!